# Why am I only getting one math.random value and how do I get more?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code. The problem is that it generates one math.random value and that's it. I need it to keep generating value after each time I click a `div`.

```
var rand = Math.random();
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(rand < .5) {
        $('div').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        });
    } else if(rand < .7) {
        $('div').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('red');
        });
    } else if(rand < .9) {
        $('div').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('purple');
        });
    } else {
        $('div').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('black');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Writing my answer......

Comment: It's because you are only setting the value of `rand` once, you need to do `rand = Math.random()` again where you want to get a new random value, being inside your `click` event.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your logic to run on every click of the div, you should have your random number generation and if tree reside inside the div clicking callback. Something like:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var rand = Math.random();
    if(rand < .5) {
       $(this).addClass('blue');
    } else if (rand < .7) {
       $(this).addClass('red');
    } 
    // and so on
});
```

Comment: Awesome I was wondering if I set a div to a certain width how can I obtain that width in javascript. If I id it 'div'

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and tell me if it needs improvement :)

***Here is a definition of the code used here...***

`Math.floor` is used to remove the decimal point from a number. To get a random number that can pull a random array element, you must convert the decimal to a whole number and make sure that it is not larger or smaller than the number of elements in the array. You can provide a range of `Math.random` by multiplying it by the greatest number you want returned. You can also tell it to return a number that is between `x` and `y` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527834/3011082).

***Note:***
Feel free to also put hex, rgb, or any color value in the array as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['green', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'blue'];
  var randomNumber = 0;
  $('div').click(function() {
    if (this.hasAttribute('data-clicked') == false) {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      this.style.backgroundColor = colors[randomNumber];
      this.setAttribute('data-clicked', '');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: You should define `randomNumber` outside of `$("div").click(…)`  and assign it no value. And inside the ` $("div").click(…)`, assign it the random number. This will not make a new variable every time a user will click which will have a good impact on the computer's memory. I hope you got it.

Comment: that is a really neat way of doing it!!

Comment: @Tbaustin Glad you like it. I will update my answer with definitions of each "new" function used so that you understand.

Comment: Something I noticed is that if i keep clicking the squares will keep changing until the become the last random in the if statement. Is there a way once they change to keep them that way?

Comment: @Tbaustin What do you mean? This code will make it able to change colors randomly forever. Sometimes the given color is the same as the last which means that you will sometimes have to click the div several times to change the color. Could you explain in more detail? Thank you :)

Comment: I just want it to change only one time once you have clicked it. Also would you know how to make like a timer on the page that keeps counting up?

Comment: @Tbaustin What would the timer be counting up?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it only generates one value bc you only generate it once. So you would have to regenerate it each time you click a button:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    rand = Math.random();
    $(this).addClass('blue');
});
```

etc